# Parallel computation on an HPC

Tags: parallelization, high-performance-clusters

This is my first time using an HPC and I am completely lost as to how to successfully launch a master kernel and a set of slave kernels. So far I have a `.sh` called `runfile.sh` that is fed to the terminal using the command `./runfile.sh` that has the following structure:

```
#!/bin/bash qsub -q dev -l walltime=00:02:00 -l select=1:ncpus=5:mem=5gb -l mathkernel=1 -P "Project_num" mat_run.sh
```

where `mat_run.sh` is given by

```
#!/bin/bash
module load mathematica-uon/10.0.1
cd /home/ppxwe/results
math -noprompt -run < parallel_test.m
```

With `parallel_test.m` the test Mathematica script that I'm trying to run. I've tried the following:

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"];
numCore=5; 
PBSKernel[host_String]:=
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine[host,"ssh -x -f -l `3` `1` /path/to/math-mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname '`2`' -subkernel -noinit",numCore]];
hostfile = Environment["PBS_NODEFILE"];

ParallelEvaluate[ (*appropriate variables*)];

ParallelTable[{t,variable[t],{t,1,10}]
```

The main code is just schematic.

This isn't working at all. When I try and run it I get the following error output:

```
bash: /path/to/math: No such file or directory
```

If anyone could help me with this I'd very much appreciate it as I'm completely stuck.

Comment: In the `LaunchKernels` command, you did not substitute in the correct path to the `math` executable. `/path/to/math` is just an example.

Comment: @Szabolcs      Ah ok. What should the correct form be like?

Comment: We can't tell you that. It depends on where `math` is on the cluster nodes.

Comment: @Szabolcs      Is there an easy standard way to find this out from the terminal for a given HPC?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are trying to connect to remote kernels? (i.e. are you trying to setup a calculation that spans different nodes?) If the calculation is to run on a single  nodes with multiple CPUs, then you could just launch the necessary subkernels with `LaunchKernels[numCore]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs      Eventually want to use more than one node, but at the moment I'm simply trying to get it working on one (which has 16 cores). Originally, I simply had `LauncKernels[16]` in at the top of my Mathematica script (Instead of `Needs[]`..etc.), however, the calculation doesn't seem to work properly. After calculating the `ParallelTable` I `Interpolation` the answer to get a function and then share this with the sub-kernels using `ParallelEvaluate`, but this information doesn't seem to be shared properly. When I tried to `NIntegrate` the result, I get an error....

Comment: @Szabolcs      ...saying that the sub-kernels don't know what the function is.

Comment: Try evaluating `$CommandLine` within Mathematica on the cluster to find the location.

Comment: @Szabolcs      I ran a Mathematica script with simply `LaunchKernels[16]`  and `$CommandLine` and the output was `{"/cm/shared/apps/Mathematica_10.0.1/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/MathKernel", "-noprompt", "-run"}`

Comment: @Szabolcs       Do I simply replace `/path/to/math` with `"/cm/shared/apps/Mathematica_10.0.1/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/MathKernel"` then?

Comment: Yes, you can try that.

Comment: @Szabolcs      I tried that and I don't get any errors for that part anymore, however, the sub-kernels are still not receiving the information about the `Interpolation` function. The output is a Mathematica error code stating that the integrand in `NIntegrate` evaluated to non-numerical values. From scanning over the error message, it appears that this is because the sub-kernels don't correctly "know" about the interpolation function that I'm passing into `NIntegrate`.